# How to prevent feed and sitemap gems from causing conflicts in Jekyll?

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, conflict

I keep running into

```
conflict in _site/sitemap.xml
conflict in _site/feed.xml

...

Automatic merge failed;
```

In Jekyll every time I swich from working from a branch to another or the gihub pages branch is updated by a third party i.e. Sitelead.  They are very time consuming to fix, sometimes it is easier to recreate the branch but is there a reason why these plugins are required in development stage? if I remove them I get the following error:

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-feed or
>   one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently
>   configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message
>   from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-feed' If you run into
>   trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

Is there a way to disable them until you are ready to deploy?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing the `_site/` directory? You shouldn't, it's automatically generated from your source code.

1. Add the line `_site/` to your `.gitignore` file. (Tell git not to track that directory in the future)
2. run `git rm -r --cached _site/` (Delete directory from git's point of view, but leave it on disk)
3. Commit and push the changes.